# Should a supporting pump be at the bottom of it's loop?

Tags: water-pressure, boiler, pump

I'm renting and the boiler is located next to my bedroom. A helper pump has been installed, but is very loud. And the boiler keeps failing, having to be reset. I heard that with water cooled CPU's the pump should be below the radiator so gravity can help. Does this also apply to pumps in bigger systems? Maybe the pump should be installed on the living room floor?

It's a Vaillant pump, roughly the size of a big fist and runs very hot.

Comment: Runs very hot might be a symptom of a problem.  If the pumps runs much above the temperature of the water, water at 180, pump at 240, then there might be a problem in the pump causing noise, bad bearing, blockage.

Comment: I don't know that it's much hotter than the hot water. Should the temperature go down if I draw a lot of cold water? Otherwise I could get a temperature gun to measure.

Comment: Most of those pump types use the water for cooling, so should be close to water temperature.  Real temperature reading will be important, since much above the water is a sign of bad bearing blockage(noisily pump).  Those pumps usually run with a slight hum when good.

Comment: Brand/model of all equipment involved and clear focused pictures should help people get you an answer.